# How do I install my microphone?

Tags: drivers, microphone

My microphone doesn't work in Ubuntu. I have a Dell Studio XPS 16 laptop.

What are the steps to install microphone support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Oli was right it was just a mixer issue. For some reason, my internal microphone was set on "mute" by default.

I fixed it by going in "gnome-volume-control", "Input" tab and unchecking "mute".

Answer (score 15):

It's installed, it's just a mixer issue. To fix:

1. Run `alsamixer`
2. Set "Digital Input" option to "Digital Mic"

More: http://www.linlap.com/wiki/dell+studio+xps+16